# Google Maps centre changing issue

Tags: javascript, google-maps, markerclusterer, geoxml3

I'm using a combination of Google Maps, GeoXML and MarkerClusterer to map historic texts to places. The user can choose the texts they want to map, and the page goes and gets the KML for those group of texts and displays it with MarkerClusterer.

Something is causing the page to recenter over India/China when new texts are selected (bottom left corner: http://lakes.jhadley.net/lit_file.htm.

Here is the primary function that deals with the map:

```
function loadMap(myLat, myLong, zoomLevel, generatedUrl) {
    var mapOptions = {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(myLat, myLong),
        zoom: zoomLevel,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 80, maxZoom: 15};
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
    markerclusterer = new MarkerClusterer(map, [], mcOptions);

    var myParser = new geoXML3.parser({
        map: map,
        singleInfoWindow:true,
        suppressInfoWindows:true,

        createMarker:function(placemark){
            var point = placemark.latlng;
            var info = "<pre" + placemark.name + "<br /><br />" + placemark.description + "</pre>";
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({position:point});

            //Suppress the speachbubbles and have them appear in a text window instead
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                var text = placemark.description.replace(/ target="_blank"/ig, "");
                showInContentWindow(text);
            });   //Add listener

            markerclusterer.addMarker(marker);
        }
    });
    myParser.parse("http://lakes.jhadley.net/generateKml/"+generatedUrl);

    function showInContentWindow(text) {
        var sidediv = document.getElementById('kwic_window');
        sidediv.innerHTML = text;
    }   //showInContentWindow
}  //function loadMap
```

I can't personally see why the map centre is being repositioned over India/China when new texts are loaded. Can anyone tell me what I'm missing?

Comment: If I (de)select something from checkbox list the map is center for a moment over Ambleside/Windermere/Kendal region. Each time.

Comment: Yes, then it moves to India/China

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- by default geoxml3 attempts to zoom to fit the data. If you don't want it to do that, set the "zoom" option to false.  From [the documentation](https://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/wiki/ParserReference):

> zoom | boolean (true) | If true, the parser will automatically move the map to a best-fit of the geodata after parsing of a KML document completes.

That is where the "center" of the markers are:

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20140312_1,4.kml

http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_geoxml3_kmltest_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_20140312_1.kml